# IPN Sandbox Testing

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Been a while since I've dealt with PP IPN.  Anyway - reworking an old client's checkout processing - one option is PP and we used IPN.  I still have a sandbox acct and used the sandbox url instead of the live PP url.

I see the purchase and a correct debit to my sandbox acct - AND I received an email from the client's server (which is sent only when the IPN is received). But the email is a bit odd in that it says....

*** THIS PAYPAL PAYMENT IS IN A PENDING STATE.
THE REASON GIVEN BY PAYPAL IS: unilateral

THIS ORDER CANNOT BE FULFILLED UNTIL THE PAYPAL STATE IS
CHANGED FROM PENDING TO COMPLETED. ***

Is there some way for me to complete the transaction in my sandbox account? It's a purchaser account - not a merchant account.  Or does my client need to go into his live merchant account to handle the test purchase?

Thanks (any pointers to relevant docs are also welcome)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the email address you are using for testing in the sandbox, is linked to an actual sandbox account and is confirmed.  This some times the case when the email address is not tied to an account and verified.  You would need to log into the sellers test sandbox account, verify that the email address is linked to that account and confirmed/verified.

Comment: Thanks Chad - I'll check it out.